# Delay Loading DWMAPI on Windows XP and CodeBlocks

Tags: c++, windows-xp, codeblocks, dwm, tdm-gcc

I have a project that I'm been fighting to build for Windows (XP) for a month solid now. The project uses gtkmm-3, C++, and the latest GCC-TDM compiler. My IDE is CodeBlocks 13.14.

I'm making progress, however, I am now getting hung up on this error message...

`ld.exe cannot find -ldwmapi`

Now, DWMAPI is a DLL only available on Windows Vista and above. According to my research, you can Delay Loading of certain DLLs in cases where they are present on *some* systems, but not on others.

The problem is, I have no clue how to do this on CodeBlocks. The `-z lazy` option does not accomplish this. If Delay Loading is impossible, how do I get around the `dwmapi` dependency. There *has* to be a way!

**Full Build Command:** (errors at bottom)

```
-------------- Clean: Debug in infiltrator (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler)---------------

Cleaned "infiltrator - Debug"

-------------- Build: Debug in infiltrator (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler)---------------

mingw32-g++-dw2.exe -std=c++11 -Wall -mms-bitfields -pthread -IC:/dev/MinGW/include/glibmm-2.4 -IC:/dev/MinGW/lib/glibmm-2.4/include -IC:/dev/MinGW/include/sigc++-2.0 -IC:/dev/MinGW/lib/sigc++-2.0/include -IC:/dev/MinGW/include/glib-2.0 -IC:/dev/MinGW/lib/glib-2.0/include -IC:/dev/MinGW/include/gtkmm-3.0 -IC:/dev/MinGW/lib/gtkmm-3.0/include -IC:/dev/MinGW/include/atkmm-1.6 -IC:/dev/MinGW/include/giomm-2.4 -IC:/dev/MinGW/lib/giomm-2.4/include -IC:/dev/MinGW/include/pangomm-1.4 -IC:/dev/MinGW/lib/pangomm-1.4/include -IC:/dev/MinGW/include/gtk-3.0 -IC:/dev/MinGW/include/cairomm-1.0 -IC:/dev/MinGW/lib/cairomm-1.0/include -IC:/dev/MinGW/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0 -IC:/dev/MinGW/include/gdkmm-3.0 -IC:/dev/MinGW/lib/gdkmm-3.0/include -IC:/dev/MinGW/include/atk-1.0 -IC:/dev/MinGW/include/pango-1.0 -IC:/dev/MinGW/include/cairo -IC:/dev/MinGW/include/pixman-1 -IC:/dev/MinGW/include -I/mingw32/include/freetype2 -I/mingw32/include/libpng16 -I/mingw32/include/harfbuzz -I/mingw32/include/glib-2.0 -I/mingw32/lib/glib-2.0/include -I/mingw32/include -IC:/dev/MinGW/include/freetype2 -IC:/dev/MinGW/include/libpng16 -IC:/dev/MinGW/include/harfbuzz -Wl,-luuid -LC:/dev/MinGW/lib -lgtkmm-3.0 -latkmm-1.6 -lgdkmm-3.0 -lgiomm-2.4 -lpangomm-1.4 -lgtk-3 -lglibmm-2.4 -lcairomm-1.0 -lgdk-3 -lgdi32 -limm32 -lshell32 -lole32 -lwinmm -ldwmapi -lz -latk-1.0 -lgio-2.0 -lpangowin32-1.0 -lpangocairo-1.0 -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lcairo-gobject -lpango-1.0 -lcairo -lsigc-2.0 -lgobject-2.0 -lglib-2.0 -lintl -std=c++11 -Wall -g -mms-bitfields -pthread -IC:/dev/MinGW/include/glibmm-2.4 -IC:/dev/MinGW/lib/glibmm-2.4/include -IC:/dev/MinGW/include/sigc++-2.0 -IC:/dev/MinGW/lib/sigc++-2.0/include -IC:/dev/MinGW/include/glib-2.0 -IC:/dev/MinGW/lib/glib-2.0/include -IC:/dev/MinGW/include/gtkmm-3.0 -IC:/dev/MinGW/lib/gtkmm-3.0/include -IC:/dev/MinGW/include/atkmm-1.6 -IC:/dev/MinGW/include/giomm-2.4 -IC:/dev/MinGW/lib/giomm-2.4/include -IC:/dev/MinGW/include/pangomm-1.4 -IC:/dev/MinGW/lib/pangomm-1.4/include -IC:/dev/MinGW/include/gtk-3.0 -IC:/dev/MinGW/include/cairomm-1.0 -IC:/dev/MinGW/lib/cairomm-1.0/include -IC:/dev/MinGW/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0 -IC:/dev/MinGW/include/gdkmm-3.0 -IC:/dev/MinGW/lib/gdkmm-3.0/include -IC:/dev/MinGW/include/atk-1.0 -IC:/dev/MinGW/include/pango-1.0 -IC:/dev/MinGW/include/cairo -IC:/dev/MinGW/include/pixman-1 -IC:/dev/MinGW/include -I/mingw32/include/freetype2 -I/mingw32/include/libpng16 -I/mingw32/include/harfbuzz -I/mingw32/include/glib-2.0 -I/mingw32/lib/glib-2.0/include -I/mingw32/include -IC:/dev/MinGW/include/freetype2 -IC:/dev/MinGW/include/libpng16 -IC:/dev/MinGW/include/harfbuzz -Wl,-luuid -LC:/dev/MinGW/lib -lgtkmm-3.0 -latkmm-1.6 -lgdkmm-3.0 -lgiomm-2.4 -lpangomm-1.4 -lgtk-3 -lglibmm-2.4 -lcairomm-1.0 -lgdk-3 -lgdi32 -limm32 -lshell32 -lole32 -lwinmm -ldwmapi -lz -latk-1.0 -lgio-2.0 -lpangowin32-1.0 -lpangocairo-1.0 -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lcairo-gobject -lpango-1.0 -lcairo -lsigc-2.0 -lgobject-2.0 -lglib-2.0 -lintl -z lazy -std=c++11 -mms-bitfields -pthread -IC:/dev/MinGW/include/glibmm-2.4 -IC:/dev/MinGW/lib/glibmm-2.4/include -IC:/dev/MinGW/include/sigc++-2.0 -IC:/dev/MinGW/lib/sigc++-2.0/include -IC:/dev/MinGW/include/glib-2.0 -IC:/dev/MinGW/lib/glib-2.0/include -IC:/dev/MinGW/include/gtkmm-3.0 -IC:/dev/MinGW/lib/gtkmm-3.0/include -IC:/dev/MinGW/include/atkmm-1.6 -IC:/dev/MinGW/include/giomm-2.4 -IC:/dev/MinGW/lib/giomm-2.4/include -IC:/dev/MinGW/include/pangomm-1.4 -IC:/dev/MinGW/lib/pangomm-1.4/include -IC:/dev/MinGW/include/gtk-3.0 -IC:/dev/MinGW/include/cairomm-1.0 -IC:/dev/MinGW/lib/cairomm-1.0/include -IC:/dev/MinGW/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0 -IC:/dev/MinGW/include/gdkmm-3.0 -IC:/dev/MinGW/lib/gdkmm-3.0/include -IC:/dev/MinGW/include/atk-1.0 -IC:/dev/MinGW/include/pango-1.0 -IC:/dev/MinGW/include/cairo -IC:/dev/MinGW/include/pixman-1 -IC:/dev/MinGW/include -I/mingw32/include/freetype2 -I/mingw32/include/libpng16 -I/mingw32/include/harfbuzz -I/mingw32/include/glib-2.0 -I/mingw32/lib/glib-2.0/include -I/mingw32/include -IC:/dev/MinGW/include/freetype2 -IC:/dev/MinGW/include/libpng16 -IC:/dev/MinGW/include/harfbuzz -Iinclude -IC:\dev\MinGW\include -c "C:\Documents and Settings\Jason\Desktop\infiltrator\main.cpp" -o obj\Debug\main.o
mingw32-g++-dw2.exe -std=c++11 -Wall -mms-bitfields -pthread -IC:/dev/MinGW/include/glibmm-2.4 -IC:/dev/MinGW/lib/glibmm-2.4/include -IC:/dev/MinGW/include/sigc++-2.0 -IC:/dev/MinGW/lib/sigc++-2.0/include -IC:/dev/MinGW/include/glib-2.0 -IC:/dev/MinGW/lib/glib-2.0/include -IC:/dev/MinGW/include/gtkmm-3.0 -IC:/dev/MinGW/lib/gtkmm-3.0/include -IC:/dev/MinGW/include/atkmm-1.6 -IC:/dev/MinGW/include/giomm-2.4 -IC:/dev/MinGW/lib/giomm-2.4/include -IC:/dev/MinGW/include/pangomm-1.4 -IC:/dev/MinGW/lib/pangomm-1.4/include -IC:/dev/MinGW/include/gtk-3.0 -IC:/dev/MinGW/include/cairomm-1.0 -IC:/dev/MinGW/lib/cairomm-1.0/include -IC:/dev/MinGW/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0 -IC:/dev/MinGW/include/gdkmm-3.0 -IC:/dev/MinGW/lib/gdkmm-3.0/include -IC:/dev/MinGW/include/atk-1.0 -IC:/dev/MinGW/include/pango-1.0 -IC:/dev/MinGW/include/cairo -IC:/dev/MinGW/include/pixman-1 -IC:/dev/MinGW/include -I/mingw32/include/freetype2 -I/mingw32/include/libpng16 -I/mingw32/include/harfbuzz -I/mingw32/include/glib-2.0 -I/mingw32/lib/glib-2.0/include -I/mingw32/include -IC:/dev/MinGW/include/freetype2 -IC:/dev/MinGW/include/libpng16 -IC:/dev/MinGW/include/harfbuzz -Wl,-luuid -LC:/dev/MinGW/lib -lgtkmm-3.0 -latkmm-1.6 -lgdkmm-3.0 -lgiomm-2.4 -lpangomm-1.4 -lgtk-3 -lglibmm-2.4 -lcairomm-1.0 -lgdk-3 -lgdi32 -limm32 -lshell32 -lole32 -lwinmm -ldwmapi -lz -latk-1.0 -lgio-2.0 -lpangowin32-1.0 -lpangocairo-1.0 -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lcairo-gobject -lpango-1.0 -lcairo -lsigc-2.0 -lgobject-2.0 -lglib-2.0 -lintl -std=c++11 -Wall -g -mms-bitfields -pthread -IC:/dev/MinGW/include/glibmm-2.4 -IC:/dev/MinGW/lib/glibmm-2.4/include -IC:/dev/MinGW/include/sigc++-2.0 -IC:/dev/MinGW/lib/sigc++-2.0/include -IC:/dev/MinGW/include/glib-2.0 -IC:/dev/MinGW/lib/glib-2.0/include -IC:/dev/MinGW/include/gtkmm-3.0 -IC:/dev/MinGW/lib/gtkmm-3.0/include -IC:/dev/MinGW/include/atkmm-1.6 -IC:/dev/MinGW/include/giomm-2.4 -IC:/dev/MinGW/lib/giomm-2.4/include -IC:/dev/MinGW/include/pangomm-1.4 -IC:/dev/MinGW/lib/pangomm-1.4/include -IC:/dev/MinGW/include/gtk-3.0 -IC:/dev/MinGW/include/cairomm-1.0 -IC:/dev/MinGW/lib/cairomm-1.0/include -IC:/dev/MinGW/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0 -IC:/dev/MinGW/include/gdkmm-3.0 -IC:/dev/MinGW/lib/gdkmm-3.0/include -IC:/dev/MinGW/include/atk-1.0 -IC:/dev/MinGW/include/pango-1.0 -IC:/dev/MinGW/include/cairo -IC:/dev/MinGW/include/pixman-1 -IC:/dev/MinGW/include -I/mingw32/include/freetype2 -I/mingw32/include/libpng16 -I/mingw32/include/harfbuzz -I/mingw32/include/glib-2.0 -I/mingw32/lib/glib-2.0/include -I/mingw32/include -IC:/dev/MinGW/include/freetype2 -IC:/dev/MinGW/include/libpng16 -IC:/dev/MinGW/include/harfbuzz -Wl,-luuid -LC:/dev/MinGW/lib -lgtkmm-3.0 -latkmm-1.6 -lgdkmm-3.0 -lgiomm-2.4 -lpangomm-1.4 -lgtk-3 -lglibmm-2.4 -lcairomm-1.0 -lgdk-3 -lgdi32 -limm32 -lshell32 -lole32 -lwinmm -ldwmapi -lz -latk-1.0 -lgio-2.0 -lpangowin32-1.0 -lpangocairo-1.0 -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lcairo-gobject -lpango-1.0 -lcairo -lsigc-2.0 -lgobject-2.0 -lglib-2.0 -lintl -z lazy -std=c++11 -mms-bitfields -pthread -IC:/dev/MinGW/include/glibmm-2.4 -IC:/dev/MinGW/lib/glibmm-2.4/include -IC:/dev/MinGW/include/sigc++-2.0 -IC:/dev/MinGW/lib/sigc++-2.0/include -IC:/dev/MinGW/include/glib-2.0 -IC:/dev/MinGW/lib/glib-2.0/include -IC:/dev/MinGW/include/gtkmm-3.0 -IC:/dev/MinGW/lib/gtkmm-3.0/include -IC:/dev/MinGW/include/atkmm-1.6 -IC:/dev/MinGW/include/giomm-2.4 -IC:/dev/MinGW/lib/giomm-2.4/include -IC:/dev/MinGW/include/pangomm-1.4 -IC:/dev/MinGW/lib/pangomm-1.4/include -IC:/dev/MinGW/include/gtk-3.0 -IC:/dev/MinGW/include/cairomm-1.0 -IC:/dev/MinGW/lib/cairomm-1.0/include -IC:/dev/MinGW/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0 -IC:/dev/MinGW/include/gdkmm-3.0 -IC:/dev/MinGW/lib/gdkmm-3.0/include -IC:/dev/MinGW/include/atk-1.0 -IC:/dev/MinGW/include/pango-1.0 -IC:/dev/MinGW/include/cairo -IC:/dev/MinGW/include/pixman-1 -IC:/dev/MinGW/include -I/mingw32/include/freetype2 -I/mingw32/include/libpng16 -I/mingw32/include/harfbuzz -I/mingw32/include/glib-2.0 -I/mingw32/lib/glib-2.0/include -I/mingw32/include -IC:/dev/MinGW/include/freetype2 -IC:/dev/MinGW/include/libpng16 -IC:/dev/MinGW/include/harfbuzz -Iinclude -IC:\dev\MinGW\include -c "C:\Documents and Settings\Jason\Desktop\infiltrator\src\agentDatabase.cpp" -o obj\Debug\src\agentDatabase.o

mingw32-g++-dw2.exe -LC:\dev\MinGW\lib -o bin\Debug\infiltrator.exe obj\Debug\main.o obj\Debug\src\agentDatabase.o obj\Debug\src\agentWindow.o obj\Debug\src\customWidgets.o obj\Debug\src\fileEncryption.o obj\Debug\src\gameWindow.o obj\Debug\src\infoWindow.o obj\Debug\src\keyGen.o obj\Debug\src\playerList.o obj\Debug\src\primaryWindow.o obj\Debug\src\setupWindow.o  -Wl,-luuid -LC:/dev/MinGW/lib -lgtkmm-3.0 -latkmm-1.6 -lgdkmm-3.0 -lgiomm-2.4 -lpangomm-1.4 -lgtk-3 -lglibmm-2.4 -lcairomm-1.0 -lgdk-3 -lgdi32 -limm32 -lshell32 -lole32 -lwinmm -ldwmapi -lz -latk-1.0 -lgio-2.0 -lpangowin32-1.0 -lpangocairo-1.0 -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lcairo-gobject -lpango-1.0 -lcairo -lsigc-2.0 -lgobject-2.0 -lglib-2.0 -lintl   -Wl,-luuid -LC:/dev/MinGW/lib -lgtkmm-3.0 -latkmm-1.6 -lgdkmm-3.0 -lgiomm-2.4 -lpangomm-1.4 -lgtk-3 -lglibmm-2.4 -lcairomm-1.0 -lgdk-3 -lgdi32 -limm32 -lshell32 -lole32 -lwinmm -ldwmapi -lz -latk-1.0 -lgio-2.0 -lpangowin32-1.0 -lpangocairo-1.0 -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lcairo-gobject -lpango-1.0 -lcairo -lsigc-2.0 -lgobject-2.0 -lglib-2.0 -lintl   -Wl,-luuid -LC:/dev/MinGW/lib -lgtkmm-3.0 -latkmm-1.6 -lgdkmm-3.0 -lgiomm-2.4 -lpangomm-1.4 -lgtk-3 -lglibmm-2.4 -lcairomm-1.0 -lgdk-3 -lgdi32 -limm32 -lshell32 -lole32 -lwinmm -ldwmapi -lz -latk-1.0 -lgio-2.0 -lpangowin32-1.0 -lpangocairo-1.0 -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lcairo-gobject -lpango-1.0 -lcairo -lsigc-2.0 -lgobject-2.0 -lglib-2.0 -lintl    
C:/dev/MinGWOld/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/5.1.0-dw2/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -ldwmapi
C:/dev/MinGWOld/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/5.1.0-dw2/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -ldwmapi
C:/dev/MinGWOld/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/5.1.0-dw2/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -ldwmapi
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Process terminated with status 1 (1 minute(s), 42 second(s))
3 error(s), 7 warning(s) (1 minute(s), 42 second(s))
```

Comment: The linker isn't finding the dwmapi.lib file.  Are you building on XP, or just targeting it?

Comment: Building on XP. I know it's not finding it, because it doesn't exist on XP.

Comment: You'll have to copy the lib from an OS that has it, or move your development to a newer OS.  If you want the linker to handle delay loading it still needs the lib file.  Or you could go old school and use `LoadModule`/`GetProcAddress` to access the functions in dwmapi.lib.

Comment: I can get the file, but I need to know that a) this WILL work on XP, and b) how to delay loading on CodeBlocks.

Comment: I can't help with CodeBlocks, but you'll still need to gracefully handle the case where the delay loading fails because you're on XP and don't have the DLL.

Answer (score 1):

Lazy linking, `-z lazy`, is the GNU linker's default on unix-like systems and
is not supported in the MinGW Windows ports. (This has nothing to do with
Code::Blocks)

I cannot fathom the hope that you repose in lazy linking to overcome
this problem, but it doesn't matter. If you can't count on some shared library
to be available on all target systems of your project one customary course
is to link the library statically in your executable. You can do that here.

The 32-bit TDM GCC that you are now using does not ship `dwmapi` in a static
library but the corresponding 64-bit toolchain does ship both 64- and 32-bit
builds of it, respectively:

```
<TDM-GCC-64-install-dir>/x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libdwmapi.a
```

and

```
<TDM-GCC-64-install-dir>/x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib32/libdwmapi.a
```

Those paths are among the linker defaults for the toolchain, so it
will link the library if you simply mention `-ldwmapi` in the linker options
(as you have done).

The absence of `libdwmapi.a` in the 32-bit toolchain may just be an anomaly, or
it may be a decision based on the fact that this library was not around until
Windows had transitioned to 64-bit in the mainstream.

You have 3 options then:

1. If you have no committment to building 32-bit you can swap to the
   corresponding 64-bit toolchain (and 64-bit libraries accross the board)
2. Swap to the 64-bit toolchain but continue to build 32-bit by adding the
   option `-m32` for the compiler and linker
3. Install the 64-bit toolchain, continue using the 32-bit toolchain,
   but add `-L<TDM-GCC-64-install-dir>/x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib32` to your
   linker search paths, after all those you have already specified.

A couple of unrelated observations:-

In this  and [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32854765/1362568) all of 
your g++ commandline options appear 3 times each! - yielding 4K commandlines that make
very tiresome parsing. With the Code::Blocks IDE, the only way in which you can have
produced this triplication is by setting all of these options once in the global
**Settings** -> **Compiler**, then again in the overall project settings **infiltrator** ->
**Build options** -> **infiltrator**, and yet again in the project Debug/Release configuration
settings **infiltrator** -> **Build options** -> **infiltrator** -> **Debug/Release**.

These 3 levels of settings form an inheritance hierarchy. Do not make *any* project
specific settings globally for any compiler. Doing so makes them properties of the
*compiler* and they will be applied to every *other* project that you build with
that compiler. Project settings that are invariant between project configurations
(Debug/Release) should be made only once at the project level. Debug and Release
options should be set only at the project configuration level.

Lastly I see that you have chosen to install the TDM-GCC-32 variant with Dwarf2
style exception handling, rather than the default package (per the executable
installer) with setjump-longjump style exception handling. This carries a risk.
While DW2 exception handling is significantly more efficient that SJLJ, it is
foreign to Windows and will fail if an exception must propagate through a Windows
library not built in the same way. The setjump-longjump mechamism, though slower,
relies on primtive, long standardized C library facilities that any
C or C++ compiler implements.

Comment: Hi Mike. Thanks again for the help. I wish this were more non-trivial. Two things: 1) This may be a stupid question, but can I run a 64-bit compiler on a 32-bit operating system (and a virtual machine at that). 2) I had to use DW2 because the libraries I was using demanded it. It is, unfortunately, darned near impossible for mere mortals to compile gtkmm and its dependencies. (I tried for three weeks.)

Comment: 1) In principle yes but MinGW stopped building a Windows 32-bit-host->64-bit-target toolchain in 2011, as 32-bit Windows petered out. It's available but too old for your code. And you only need the 64-bit TDM toolchain to cherrypick `lib32\libdwmapi.a`. No need to use it. 2) The DW2 may well work out as most likely any libraries to which you kick up a DW2 exception will be other ones that you have built yourself. Or at least ones that expect it.

Comment: The fact that you are doing all this in a Windows VM suggests you're more at home in Linux. If so you do have the option of doing your dev with the MinGW toolchain hosted on Linux, and relegate the VM to testing-as-you-go purposes. See http://mingw-w64.org/doku.php/download.

Comment: I have it installed, but I cannot point to the Compatible libraries.